# Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'httpOptions'

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework

Following along in a tutorial currently to integrate Angular into my Django application, I am having trouble with implementing the service to pull data from the Django REST Framework API.

I keep getting an error saying "Cannot find name 'httpOptions'" and I don't know how to resolve it.

teacher.service.ts

```
import {UserService} from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class TeacherService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private _userService: UserService) { }

  // Uses http.get() to load data from a single API endpoint
  list() {
    return this.http.get('/api/teachers');
  }

  // send a POST request to the API to create a new data object
  create(post, token) {
    httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token   // this is our token from the UserService (see Part 1)
      })
    };
    return this.http.post('/api/teachers', JSON.stringify(post), httpOptions);
  }
}
```

relevant user.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private httpOptions: any;
  public token: string;
  public token_expires: Date;
  public username: string;
  public errors: any = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: What file is this error occurring in? You may need to declare httpOptions as a variable in your create function i.e. `const httpOptions = { ...`

Comment: your `httpOptions ` need to be declared, which is `const httpOptions = ....`

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your issue.

```
create(post, token) {
let appHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token   
  });

return this.http.post('/api/teachers', JSON.stringify(post), { headers: appHeaders });
}
```

Or something simple like the following can fix the issue.

```
let httpOptions = { ... }
```

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are accessing a global variable and not using this. So try this,

```
return this.http.post('/api/teachers', JSON.stringify(post), this.httpOptions);
```

Or you have to define method createPost like this, (define a local variable)

```
create(post, token) {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token   // this is our token from the UserService (see Part 1)
      })
    };
    return this.http.post('/api/teachers', JSON.stringify(post), httpOptions);
  }
```